# My kubernetes ingress shows off a weird output

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am currently learning Kubernetes through the Docker Desktop of MacbookPro M1. But when I deploy my ingress I get a weird output, the host which should be the app-example.com just shows a '*':
[image]

[image]

And it is the yaml file of this ingress:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbeLK.png)
How could I fix it?

Comment: Remove `-` (or to be more precise - replace it with a space) in front of `http` as it creates a new object.

Answer (score 0):

You added extra - in your yaml, which may be resulting in this behaviour. Below is the sample ingress object config

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-wildcard-host
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "foo.bar.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/bar"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
```